# jQuery toggle function fails after a while

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a jQuery toggling function that looks like this:

```
// category filter
$.fn.clickToggle = function(a, b) {
  var ab = [b, a];
  function cb(){ ab[this._tog^=1].call(this); }
  return this.on('click', cb);
};

$.fn.swapClass = function(oldClass, newClass) {
  return $(this).removeClass(oldClass)
                .addClass(newClass)
                .fadeIn('fast');
};

$('.category-filter').clickToggle(function() {
  // clear old
  $('.category-filter').each(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
    $(this).swapClass('label-success', 'label-default');
  })

  // get new
  var category = $(this).attr('data-category');
  $(this).swapClass('label-default', 'label-success');

  // apply new
  $('.category-filter').each(function() {
    if (!($(this).attr('data-category').indexOf(category) >= 0)) {
      $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    }
  })
  $('.article_container').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-categories').indexOf(category) >= 0) {
      $(this).fadeIn('fast');
    } else {
      $(this).fadeOut('fast');
    }
  })
}, function() {
  $(this).swapClass('label-success', 'label-default');
  $('.article_container').each(function() { $(this).fadeIn('fast') })
  $('.category-filter').each(function() { $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1.0) })
});
```

It works okay—see JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/uh123qwx/1/)—but after clicking one link and then "skipping" to click another link the toggle seems to break.

What's wrong with my function? How can I change it so it toggles whether a user clicks the same link again or another link next?

Answer (score 2):

It is because even though you've changed the style of the other elements when you click on one, you haven't changed the `._tog` value.

You are trying to maintain the state in two different ways.  One through ._tog and another through the classes label-success/label-default.  I would suggest not using `._tog` at all and rely on the classes.  In fact, I'd greatly simplify your whole javascript.

Update sorry, this is just a quick answer, I have to run, but here ya go:
https://jsfiddle.net/uh123qwx/3/

```js
$('.category-filter').click(function(){
    $('.category-filter').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.category-filter { background-color: #777; transition: all .5s ease-in-out; }
.category-filter.active { color: green; background-color: #5cb85c; }

.category-filter.active[data-category='custom article'] ~ div > .article_container:not([data-categories*='custom article']),
.category-filter.active[data-category='retirement'] ~ div > .article_container:not([data-categories*='retirement']),
.category-filter.active[data-category='property'] ~ div > .article_container:not([data-categories*='property'])
{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="label category-filter" data-category="custom article">custom article</span>
<span class="label category-filter" data-category="retirement">retirement</span>
<span class="label category-filter" data-category="property">property</span>

<div>
  <div class="article_container" data-categories="custom article">
    <p>Custom</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article_container" data-categories="custom article">
    <p>Another custom</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article_container" data-categories="retirement">
    <p>Retirement</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article_container" data-categories="property">
    <p>Property</p>
  </div>
  <div class="article_container" data-categories="property retirement">
    <p>Property and retirement</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Updated with a quick example

Comment: That is *seriously* awesome. Thanks so much!

Comment: Your solution though means I have to hard-code those categories into the CSS which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't creating your plugins properly and can get them do do a lot more of the work for you.

First it's important to realize that when the selector matches more than one element...`this` in plugin includes the whole collection.

Thus a plugin generally includes a `this.each()` section to insulate instances. Often it will look like `return this.each(){ //instance code });`

Rather than iterating collections in the plugin where it would normally be done, you have a whole bunch of iterations over the same element collections in your other code that really don't need to be there

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your meaning here. How should I "properly" create my plugin? Do you mean the functions at the top?

Comment: no ... more about recognizing the `each` part. Most of the heavy lifting and looping should be in plugin not in the standalone code...not to mention that `this.something()` affects the whole collection